# Save XML file without formatting

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I have a XML file that needs to be saved without formatting, without identation and line breaks. I'm doing it this way:

```
using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText("E:\\nfse.xml"))
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = false };
    doc.Load("E:\\notafinal.xml");
    writer.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

But that way I need to create the file, and then I need to change it 3 times, so in the end there are a total of 4 files, the initial one and the result of the  3 changes.

When I save the file, I do it this way:

```
 MemoryStream stream = stringToStream(soapEnvelope);
 webRequest.ContentLength = stream.Length;
 Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
 stream.WriteTo(requestStream);

 document.LoadXml(soapEnvelope);
 document.PreserveWhitespace = false;
 document.Save(@"E:\\notafinal.xml");
```

How can I do this without having to create a new document?

Comment: Overwrite the file?

Comment: Yes, but of the form without jumping line, the same I do when I create a new one.

Comment: What do you mean by the jumping line? You mean only editing the line within the XML file which is changed?

Comment: When generating the xml, I need everything to be in a single line, and do not skip any lines, because if this happens I can not validate the signature.

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957109/10716861) where they describe about how to Overwrite a XML file. Maybe it can be usefull for you. Link provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/10716861/eduardo-tomasi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save XML without formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501298/save-xml-without-formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to eliminate extra space by not formatting the XML file, you could use `XmlWriterSettings` and `XmlWriter`, like this:

```
public void SaveXmlDocToFile(XmlDocument xmlDoc,
                             string outputFileName,
                             bool formatXmlFile = false)
{
   var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
   if (formatXmlFile)
   {
      settings.Indent = true;
   }
   else
   {
      settings.Indent = false;
      settings.NewLineChars = String.Empty;
   }
   using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputFileName, settings))
      xmlDoc.Save(writer);
}
```

Passing `formatXmlFile = false` in the parameters will save the XML file without formatting it.

Comment: I just saw that you've asked basically the same question yesterday and got [an answer just like mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506007/8133067), but you've accepted mine and not the other one. Did my answer really work for you?